# ReferenceError: google is not defined (error after ajax call)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I got this error message for the google map after using ajax call.

```
ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

What I'm doing is I put the link "`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>`" inside the file(showMap.php) being called by ajax.

However, if i refresh the page, the google map work fine. And if I put the link mentioned outside the file being called by ajax, for example(mainPage.php) , the google maps work fine also. Any idea on how to make the link working inside the showMap.php file?

Comment: are you calling references from that file before the ajax response has returned? are you making references to google in your own code?

Comment: update question with relevant  code.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is your code is executing before the Google library is loaded.

In order to execute the code for the map, reference it as a callback function on the Google Maps API URL.

For example: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=init">/script>`

```
  <script>
function init() {
//doStuffWithMapsAp
};
</script>
```